# Calculate the area between $f(x) = x \cos^2(x)$ and $g(x) = x$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, area

I want to calculate the area bounded by the curves $f(x) = x \cos^2(x)$ and $g(x) = x$.

To find the points of intersection, I set $f(x)= g(x)$.

$$\begin{aligned}x\cos^2(x)&= x\\
x\cos^2(x)-x&= 0\\
x[cos^2(x)-1] &= 0\\
x[\cos(x)-1]\cdot[\cos(x)+1] &= 0\end{aligned}$$

I find as intersections $x = k \pi$ , with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

My issue is that there are no clear boundaries for this function (periodical so with a lot of intersections between curves), so I don't know what the bounds $a$ and $b$ of the integral are supposed to be. (None were given in the questions)

[Plot of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZHTF.jpg)

The value of the integral is
$$\frac{1}{8} (\cos(2 x) + 2 x (-x + \sin(2 x))) $$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: That answer you quote seems to be just the calculation of the indefinite integral. I don't think you can calculate the area without giving an interval of integration

Comment: That´s specifically my issue, the teacher asked to calculate the area based on the intersectionS (not possible as no an intervals were given). I read somewhere it was possible using improper integrals ?

Comment: Are you studying even and odd functions? If so, perhaps you teacher had in mind an interval such as $[-a,a]$ for some $a>0$.

Answer (score 1):

The area you are seeking does not exist as a real number (if even the negative integrals in the $(-\infty,0]$ region are turned to positive), rather the integral which represents the area you are looking for diverges. Note that, if $A$ is the  area,
\begin{align} A &= \lim_{t \to +\infty}-{\int_{-t}^{0}{x(1-\cos^2{x})\mathrm{d}x}+\int_0^t{x(1-\cos^2{x})\mathrm{d}x}} \\ 
&= -\int_{-\infty}^{0}{x(1-\cos^2{x})\mathrm{d}x}+\int_0^{+\infty}{x(1-\cos^2{x})\mathrm{d}x} \\
&=2\int_0^{+\infty}{x(1-\cos^2{x})\ \mathrm{d}x} 
\\
&= \int_0^{+\infty}{x(1-\cos{2x})}\mathrm{d}x \\
&=  \int_0^{+\infty}{x \ \mathrm{d}x} \ - \int_0^{+\infty}{x\cos{2x} 
 \ \mathrm{d}x} \\
&= \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x\sin{2x}}{2}-\frac{\cos{2x}}{4}\Biggr|_0^{+\infty} \\
&= \lim_{x \to +\infty}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x\sin{2x}}{2}-\frac{\cos{2x}}{4}\right) + 1\rightarrow+\infty\end{align}
as $-1 \leq \sin{x}, \cos{x} \leq 1$ so the limit diverges. If you are still not convinced, see that the integral can be written as:
\begin{align}
A &= 2\int_0^{+\infty}{x(1-\cos^2{x})\mathrm{d}x} \\
&= {\sum_{k =0}^{+\infty}{\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}}{x(1-\cos^2{x})\mathrm{d}x}} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\Biggr[\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x\sin{2x}}{2}-\frac{\cos{2x}}{4}+1\Biggr]_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{(2k+1)\pi^2}{2}}
\end{align}
for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ which also obviously diverges (and now you can even terminate at a partial sum and find the of a section). If the teacher wanted you to just find the integral (which isn't really the area in this case):
\begin{align}
I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{x(1-\cos^2{x})\mathrm{d}x}=0
\end{align}
since $f(x)=x(1-\cos^2{x})$ is an odd function.